# how to solve the problem in this code class darts after update

Tags: dart

I want to ask something, yesterday I was using Dart version 2.10, after I upgraded to version 2.13, I can't run this code can someone help me

```
class AmtException implements Exception {
  String errMsg() => 'Amount should be greater than zero';
}

void withdraw_amt(int amt) {
  if (amt <= 0) {
    throw new AmtException();
  }
}

 void main() {
   try {
     withdraw_amt(-1);
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.errMsg());
   } finally {
     print('Ending requested operation.....');
   }
 }
```

This output :

```
Error: The method 'errMsg' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'errMsg'.

print(e.errMsg());
        ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Fix `catch (e)` to `on AmtException catch (e)` so that you catch the exception as the correct type.  Or change `AmtException.errMsg()` to `AmtException.toString()` so your `catch` block doesn't need to call a method specific to your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code:

```
class AmtException implements Exception {
  String errMsg() => 'Amount should be greater than zero';
}

void withdraw_amt(int amt) {
  if (amt <= 0) {
    throw new AmtException();
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    withdraw_amt(-1);
  } on AmtException catch (e) {
    print(e.errMsg());
  } finally {
    print('Ending requested operation.....');
  }
}
```

Thanks @jamesdlin